# symfony2 login not working FOSUSerBundle

Tags: php, session, authentication, symfony, fosuserbundle

Help! I don't know why, but recently I can no longer log into my Symfony2 website. When I try to login, I simply get redirected back to the login page with no error, and no indication of what is wrong. I've cleared my apc cache, my prod and dev caches, and I've been able to reproduce the error in both dev and prod. I've set g+wrx and u+rwx recursively.

How do I debug a login page when no exception is being thrown? The error occurs in multiple browsers on multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a de-sync between the form_login check_path in my security.yml and the root of my FOSUserBundle routing information. Because the two didn't sync up, clicks on the login page would simply result in a page redirect rather than passing it to the login classes.

Comment: Pleas PLEASE tell me you can still elaborate on this a bit more!! I am working a legacy project and I have EXACTLY this problem... Do you still have the configurations? I don't have check_path set in my security.yml so I don't really understand where my de-sync might come from.